# How can one implement is_aggregate without compiler magic?

Tags: c++, c++20, sfinae, type-traits, aggregate-initialization

Aggregate initialization is a special form of list initialization which can be used for aggregate types.

> An aggregate is an array or a class ([class]) with
> **(1.1)** no user-declared or inherited constructors ([class.ctor]),
> **(1.2)** no private or protected direct non-static data members ([class.access]),
> **(1.3)** no virtual functions ([class.virtual]), and
> **(1.4)** no virtual, private, or protected base classes ([class.mi]).

[See the C++20 standard, `dcl.init.aggr#1`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/dcl.init.aggr#1)

I'm wondering if we can test for these requirements without compiler magic.

##### Definitely Possible

The polymorphism part of `1.3` and `1.4` is covered by [`std::is_polymorphic`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_polymorphic), which exploits the fact that `dynamic_cast` is only valid for polymorphic classes.

##### Probably Impossible

How can we test whether out bases classes are inherited-from `private`ly? And how can we do so for our data members? There are no reflections that would list all of our members or bases classes, let alone their access specifiers.

But the requirement I'm most interested in is `1.1`, which would need to detect if we have no user-declared constructors. Even an explicitly defaulted constructor is user-declared.

```cpp
struct Aggregate {};
struct NonAggregate { NonAggregate() = default; };
```

How can we possibly distinguish `Aggregate` and `NonAggregate`? We would need an expression that is ill-formed for one but not for the other, then use SFINAE. However, both can be default-initialized and value-initialized. See [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/61YE1qsEd) to confirm that `NonAggregate` is indeed not an aggregate type (since C++20).

Comment: "I'm wondering if we can test for these requirements without compiler magic." - Why would anyone need this?

Comment: @Jodocus perhaps if one wanted to implement their own standard library that's more self-hosted. I'm mainly asking this question out of curiosity.

Comment: That would be a hopeless endeavour. There are many more type trait templates that require compiler intrinsics, think about stuff as `std::is_empty`. I do not think that you can make a *complete* implementation of the C++20 standard library without compiler support.